# How to separate code from types in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings, transpiler

I would like, instead of mixing code and types like this:

```
const compar8 : boolean | error = (action: string, n: number) => {
    switch(action) {
        case 'greater':
            return n > 8;
        case 'less':
            return n < 8;
        case 'equal':
            return n === 8;
        default:
            throw new Error('Invalid action');
    }
}
```

to have something like this:

```
// code.js

const compar8 = (action, n) => {
    switch(action) {
        case 'greater':
            return n > 8;
        case 'less':
            return n < 8;
        case 'equal':
            return n === 8;
        default:
            throw new Error('Invalid action');
    }
}

// types.ts
compar8 : (string, number) => boolean | error
```

The reason is 1. more readable and 2. assign same types to certain function, ex:

```
myType = (string, number) => boolean | error
```

and then use it for all the functions that have the same signature:

```
// types.ts

compar8: myType
compar9: myType
...
etc
```

Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: `type myType = (string, number) => boolean | error` will work just fine, yes, then `const compar8: myType = ...`. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#function-types. Note `const compar8 : boolean | error` isn't right at all, because the value is a *function*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just declare it as a `type` ahead of time:

```
type Compar8 = (compare: string, n: number) => boolean;
const compar8: Compar8 = (compare, n) => {
    switch(action) {
        case 'greater':
            return n > 8;
        case 'less':
            return n < 8;
        case 'equal':
            return n === 8;
        default:
            throw new Error('Invalid action');
    }
}
```

Note that since you're not *returning* an error, it shouldn't be included in the type. The type of an exception that may get thrown isn't noted in TypeScript. You'd do `=> boolean | error` only if you had something like `return new Error()`. (*not* `throw`).

Comment: @ entropyfever - And if you like, the type can be in exported by `types.ts` and imported by the code defining `compar8`.

Comment: @ CertainPerformance About returning and not throwing the error, what is it consider best practice in Typescript ? Should I have something like: ```myFun: success_response | error1 | error2 | error3``` or catching the different errors ?

Comment: @entropyfever If you really need static type-checking to differentiate between different possible errors, you can do that, but it's kind of weird to need such a thing I think. Simply knowing that an error is returned or thrown would be enough in almost all situations IMO (and the precise error can then be narrowed down at runtime if needed)